# How to make it so that My SplashState will switch to my MenuState after few seconds

Tags: java

I have a SplashScreen class( SplashState) which will show first when someone opens my game, and what i want to do is that my Game will show the SplashState for lets say 5 seconds and after 5 seconds, it will switch to my MenuState. 
How can I do that(btw im a noob in java, sorry if I got you cringed)

My SplashScreen class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class SplashScreen extends State {

private int duration;
private boolean running = false;

public SplashScreen(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);

}

@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(Assets.Splash, 0, 0, 1280, 720, null);
}

@Override
public void tick() {
    if(handler.getMouseManager().isMiddlePressed())
        State.setState(handler.getGame().menuState);

}

public void run() {

}

public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(int duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

}
```

My State Class(because my splash state extends to this class)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import com.vescorspel.game.MyFirstGame.Handler;

public abstract class State {

private static State currentState = null;

public static State setState(State state){
    return currentState = state;
}

public static State getState(){
    return currentState;
}

//CLASS

protected Handler handler;

public State(Handler handler){
    this.handler = handler;
}

public abstract void tick();

public abstract void render(Graphics g);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something simple like:

```
// private variables
private long lastTime = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
//this is how long it has been running for 
private long totalTime = 0;

// Then in the render method
long now = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
long delta = now - lastTime;
totalTime += delta;
lastTime = now;

//Check if 5 seconds has elapsed
if(totalTime > 5000)
    setState(mainmenu);
```